# UIAlertView delegate functions not invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertview

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: NSDictionary) {
    let aps: NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary
    UpdatesViewController().newArticle(aps) 
}
```

UpdatesViewController:

```
class UpdatesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    func newArticle(userInfo: NSDictionary) {
        let title: NSString = userInfo["alert"] as NSString
        UIAlertView(title: "New update", message: title, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss", otherButtonTitles: "Read more").show()
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, willDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println(buttonIndex)
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println(buttonIndex)
    }
}
```

I receive the `UIAlertView` with the correct message from APNS when a push notification is sent. The problem is that when either of the two buttons is pressed in the `UIAlertView` the press is not logged via `println`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `UpdatesViewController()` creates a new instance of `UpdatesViewController`. This will be released before the delegate gets called because its not retained anywhere. Are you trying to call the function in the existing view controller?

Comment: Better to say "there is no strong reference".

Answer (score 1):

as of iOS8 `UIAlertView` Delegate are deprecated.
Use `UIAlertViewController` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. Use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` instead.

//sample code display alert

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { enter code here }
```